# Display text for hyperlink in powerapps

Tags: hyperlink, powerapps

I am new to Powerapps. I have created a customized form for a Sharepoint list using Power Apps. I only have the ability to include a field to store the URL address, but I want the display text to appear in the customized form (not the whole url) and I want the display text to be seen in the view mode of the SP list.

How can I do this?

Thank you

I have tried to insert html text box inside the card

```
<a href= 'https://url link> text to be displayed</a>
```

It worked but is it doesn't appear in the SP List view

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because of a SharePoint limitation. Power Apps communicates with SharePoint by using SP's data API, and that API doesn't return the display text of a hyperlink column. For example, I created a new SP list with one such column:

[image: SP List with a calculated column]

And referenced it in Power Apps, with the [monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/monitor-overview) connected to see what is going over the network, and there is no "Stack overflow" text in the response:

[image: Response from the network]

There is a [post in the community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Displaying-text-from-a-sharepoint-list-hyperlink-column/td-p/435752) that says that you can get the value from a Power Automate flow, but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [HTML Text control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN5Ii.png)?

Please refer below image of quick demo I created.

Here, `WebSite` is a `URL` field in CRM.

[image: Setup Html Text control in power apps]